# Write NetCDF variables in Python loop

Tags: python, netcdf

I would to create a NetCDF file using Python for multiple variables.
For instance, for one variable I can write something like that:

```
       hourlygrp = ds.createGroup("hourly_data")

       Cos_SZA_dim = hourlygrp.createDimension('Cos_SZA',744)
       Cos_SZA= hourlygrp.createVariable('Cos_SZA','f4',('Cos_SZA'),)
       Cos_SZA[:] = np.squeeze(hourly_mean[0, :])
       Cos_SZA.units = “Degrees”
```

Which it works, while if I want to do it for all the variables I have in a loop I am doing it like that:

```
       hourlygrp = ds.createGroup("hourly_data")

       for i, vname in enumerate(var_name):

           var_dim  = hourlygrp.createDimension(vname, 744)
           vname = hourlygrp.createVariable(vname, 'f4', (vname))
           vname[:] =  np.squeeze(hourly_mean[i, :])
           vname.units = var_unit[I]
```

But when I run the code I got an error like:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dimensions'

[....]

ValueError: cannot find dimension C in this group or parent groups

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce this error from the limited info you have given.

It's a little unusual to be turning every variable into a dimension. Judging by the 744, it looks as if your main (only ?) dimension is time.

I personally find `xarray` easier for basic netcdf creation.

Comment: @RobertDavy thanks for your reply. I am new using Python, I could quickly implement this into one single loop?. Thanks again.

Comment: I do recommend you become familiar with `xarray` library. Basically, you would need to create `DataArray` object for each variable, each with time as the coordinate. https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html
Then add all the `DataArray` objects to a `Dataset` object. The `Dataset` object can be initially created from the first 'DataArray' variable using `to_dataset()`. Subsequent data arrays can be added to that.
Then you can use the `to_netcdf()` method of the `Dataset`.

Comment: Also, whatever processing you are doing, make sure it could not be done more easily (and without coding) using `nco` or `cdo` command line tools.

Comment: @RobertDavy thanks :)